# Old ReplicaSet not getting replaced by new ReplicaSet after an kubectl edit

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset, kubernetes-deployment

I am creating a deployment using [this yaml](https://pastebin.com/nCLTigF7) file. It creates a replica of 4 busybox pods. All fine till here.

But when I edit this deployment using the command `kubectl edit deployment my-dep2`, only changing the version of busybox image to 1.31 (a downgrade but still an update from K8s point of view), the ReplicaSet is not completely replaced.

The output of `kubectl get all --selector app=my-dep2` post the edit is:

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-dep2-55f67b974-5k7t9   0/1     ErrImagePull       2          5m26s
pod/my-dep2-55f67b974-wjwfv   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          5m26s
pod/my-dep2-dcf7978b7-22khz   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          12m
pod/my-dep2-dcf7978b7-2q5lw   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          12m
pod/my-dep2-dcf7978b7-8mmvb   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          12m

NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/my-dep2   0/4     2            0           12m

NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/my-dep2-55f67b974   2         2         0       5m27s
replicaset.apps/my-dep2-dcf7978b7   3         3         0       12m
```

As you can see from the output above, there are 2 ReplicaSet which are existing in parallel. I expect the old ReplicaSet to be completely replaced by new ReplicaSet (containing the 1.31 version of busybox). But this is not happening. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please, consider to read about `Failed deployment` ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment ), and `Rolling update strategy` ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment )

Comment: You have not accepted any of the proposed answers and you have not pointed any further comments when they don't resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is totally normal, expected result, related with [Rolling Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) mechanism in **kubernetes**

Take a quick look at the following working example, in which I used [sample nginx `Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment). Once it's deployed, I run:

```
kubectl edit deployments.apps nginx-deployment
```

and removed the image tag which actually equals to performing an update to `nginx:latest`. Immediatelly after applying the change you can see the following:

```
$ kubectl get all --selector=app=nginx
NAME                                    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-bvmln   0/1     Terminating         0          2m6s
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-zfzmh   1/1     Running             0          2m6s
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-zskkk   1/1     Running             0          2m7s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-88fdm    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-btvgv    1/1     Running             0          3s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/nginx-deployment   ClusterIP   10.3.247.159   <none>        80/TCP    6d4h

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment   3/3     2            3           2m7s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-574b87c764   2         2         2       2m7s
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4    2         2         1       3s
```

As you can see, at certain point in time there are running pods in both replicas. It's because of the mentioned rolling update mechanism, which ensures your app availability when it is being updated.

When the update process is ended replicas count in the old `replicaset` is reduced to 0 so there are no running pods, managed by this `replicaset` as the new one achieved its desired state:

```
$ kubectl get all --selector=app=nginx
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-88fdm   1/1     Running   0          10s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-btvgv   1/1     Running   0          12s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-db5z7   1/1     Running   0          8s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/nginx-deployment   ClusterIP   10.3.247.159   <none>        80/TCP    6d4h

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment   3/3     3            3           2m16s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-574b87c764   0         0         0       2m16s
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4    3         3         3       12s
```

You may ask yourself: why is it still there ? why it is not deleted immediatelly after the new one becomes ready. Try the following:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         <none>
```

As you can see, there are 2 revisions of our rollout for this deployment. So now we may want to simply undo this recent change:

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deployment nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment rolled back
```

Now, when wee look at our replicas we can observe a reverse process:

```
$ kubectl get all --selector=app=nginx
NAME                                    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-6j7l5   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-m7956   1/1     Running             0          4s
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-v2r75   1/1     Running             0          3s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-88fdm    0/1     Terminating         0          3m25s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-btvgv    1/1     Running             0          3m27s
pod/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4-db5z7    0/1     Terminating         0          3m23s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/nginx-deployment   ClusterIP   10.3.247.159   <none>        80/TCP    6d4h

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment   3/3     3            3           5m31s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-574b87c764   3         3         2       5m31s
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4    1         1         1       3m27s
```

Note, that there is no need to create a 3rd `replicaset`, as there is still the old one which can be used to undo our recent change. The final result looks as follows:

```
$ kubectl get all --selector=app=nginx
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-6j7l5   1/1     Running   0          40s
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-m7956   1/1     Running   0          43s
pod/nginx-deployment-574b87c764-v2r75   1/1     Running   0          42s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/nginx-deployment   ClusterIP   10.3.247.159   <none>        80/TCP    6d4h

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment   3/3     3            3           6m10s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-574b87c764   3         3         3       6m10s
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-6fcf476c4    0         0         0       4m6s
```

I hope that the above example helped you to realize why this old `replicaset` isn't immediatelly removed and what it can be still useful for.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the errors `ErrImagePull` and `CrashLoopBackOff`. Those are telling you it is not being possible to run new containers (the image was not found in the docker registry), so old ones are kept to ensure the service runs (blue-green default/rolling update).

#### Edit

Also, your Busybox containers start and run nothing (as far as I can remember) and then finish, which causes Kubernetes to restart it and never arrive to an `alive` state. Maybe you'd better run some `sleep 300` to it's entrypoint?

Answer (score 0):

as @emi said busybox and alpine etc don't do anything in case you give an explicit command. Kubernetes try to keep running but the default container does not perform any action and at the end, Kubernetes say okay, something is wrong no need to try to restart the container again and again. For test purposes, it might look as below.

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: enginx
  - image: alpine
    name: alpine
    command: ["sleep", "3600"]
```